# Same login in Wordpress and SMF

Tags: database, wordpress, session, authentication, smf

I would like use the same login in Wordpress and SMF.

Same login = same table and rows in data base or same session.

I don't know how I can do it. I've looked for plugins or modules but I can't find anything appropiate.
I've thought use OpenID, but I'm not too keen on it... Do somebody have a better idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I use smf2wp, it works perfect!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/smf2wp/